# Is there a way to call a static function without having to mention the type?

Tags: c#

Simple question, I don't think it's possible but have been surprised before.

I have a library with all kind of math functions, lets take a very simple example floorcap:

```
class MathLib {
    public static double floorcap(double floor, double value, double cap) {
        return Math.Min(Math.Max(floor, value), cap);
    }
}
```

In another method in another class, I'd like to just type

```
var mat_adjusted = floorcap(1, maturity, 5);
```

But that doesn't work, because it's not declared in this class, it's in a library. It makes me type

```
var mat_adjusted = MathLib.floorcap(1, maturity, 5);
```

wich adds noise to the code. I could shorten it to

```
using m = MyMathLibrary.MathLib;

.. yadayada

var mat_adjusted = m.floorcap(1, maturity, 5);
```

but still, I'd prefer not to have to type the class name all the time. Is that possible? I write code in F# too and you kinda get used to not having to spell out the type/module etc after a while. When I have to write C# this thing annoys me (a little) because it distracts from the actaul 'meat of the thing'.

There are a lot of functions here, when you need to call a few functions nested etc all these dots and class names add up. I like my code as clean as possible.

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Comment: Yes, use the method from within the same class. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you have such a problem with the dot notation--`MathLib.FloorCap(1, 2, 3)` looks very clean to me and is only a few characters more.

Comment: actaully considered both extension methods and 'local wrappers', forgot to metntion those in the example. Wrappers add a lot of overhead, extension methods would clutter the code too.. The point is that the code should look as much as possible as what the non-programmers would write down.

Comment: @Ron see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_IRB  for instance, wand there's a LOT more where that came from. Clean code really matters when functions get more complicated and start stacking.

Comment: How do extension methods clutter the code exactly? They are nearly identical in usage to your 'ideal' example.

Comment: I've written gobs of equation heavy code and I've never had a problem fully qualifying functions.  I think we just have different ideas as to what clean code looks like ;)

Comment: No it's not possible and I think that is a __good thing__. Making static members availbale globally w/o a context would lead to all sorts of name conflicts. Don't confuse clean code with short code.

Comment: @Ron Yeah, actually when I moved into c++ first after a lot of C# I was annoyed by all these functions coming out of thin air, I wanted to know where they came from, wich class. Now I'm asking for it exactly that. I want the code to be clean, so it looks just like the spec. Really splitting hairs here I know 8-)

Comment: @Henk good point. Code always has to unambiguous, writing does have that problem to the same extent since you can assume the context, the compiler cannot.

Comment: I think the problem could be because MathLib is not a very good name for the class.

Comment: @Henk thinking about it, why couldn't say 'open MathLib' for instance at the top of the file and let the compiler take that into account when resolving function calls. The scope of that statement would be the source file, so it would not add naming conflicts right? IT would bloat the langauge a little, but would be analogue to 'using XX ' where you no longer have to specify the namespace for a type.

Comment: @Mongus, what would you suggest then? I'd still have to type something.

Comment: @gjvdkamp, firstly - obviously its a library - so you can drop the Lib part of the name. The String class is just called String, not StringClass. The name should imply its functionality not its implementation.

Comment: Then coming up with a suitable name depends on the context really. There is no limit to how many static classes you can have, nor to the minimum number of methods allowed in a static class. Floorcap looks like it is setting a value within some limits, so maybe Limit is a decent name.. *Limit.Floorcap*. Or perhaps *Floorcap.Limit*. *Range.Limit*.. *Floor.Cap*. *Cap.Floor*...

Comment: ah ok I see, I just made that name up for the example, the real thing is called 'BaselFunctions'. I wanted a clean example without details that could distract. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible - it has to be qualified to the extent of where it resides (obviously if the thing resides *within* scope of your current context, then you could, but that misses the point of the question and objective.)

This is because nothing directly lives higher than any types etc, - so there is no sense of a "global call", so to speak.

Comment: Because it is possible via an extension method.

Comment: @Jonathon Dickinson: No it isn't - see my comment to InvisibleBacon's answer.

Comment: I agree with @Mr. Disappointment.  It's not possible outside of the class.  What the others are describing is creating a NEW unqualified method, not how to call the original method unqualified.

Comment: @Mr. According to HIS question it is possible "I'd prefer not to have to type the class name all the time", means being able using a local **variable** suffices (not meant as an insult, you are aware what extension methods are?).

Comment: It doesn't matter what it compiles to, **HE** just wants to **USE** it with as little fuss as possible.

Comment: Hi all, I'm with Mr. Dissapointment here, it has to be really clean, like an unqualified call. Extension methods would save on typing, but they woudl also turn the code 'inside out' compared to how you'd write it on a whiteboard for instance. It needs to feel 'natural'.

Comment: @Jonathon Dickinson: Fortunately I tend not to extrapolate my own rules based on what someone _didn't_ say.

Comment: I think we're debating over whether or not the extension method is a good idea. That's not the question though, the question is just about minimizing the code, which is what the extension method does. I would agree that this is not always a good idea.

Comment: @InvisibleBacon: Short code, in and of itself, is not a solution: `a.Blah(243546);`, or `b1.Brrrrr("BOOM");` What the deuce is `a`, `b1`?? And typing a meaningful variable name would presumably lead to something the length of the class name they thought they were escaping from qualifying. My answer stands: not possible.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Agreed, short code is not necessarily better in terms of readability. But gjvdkamp wasn't asking for readable code, he was asking for short code. No father gives his son a snake when he asks for bread, but what do you do if he asks for a snake? :)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to make an extension method instead. For instance, if you define your example function in a static class:

```
static class MathLib
{
    public static double floorcap(this double value, double floor, double cap)
    {
        return Math.Min(Math.Max(floor, value), cap);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var mat_adjusted = maturity.floorcap(1, 5);
```

Comment: You still need to qualify it: whether that's by static class name, type name, it's a qualified call.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Yes but the OP wanted less code to type; this gives him nearly the bare minimum code and lines up reasonably well with his desired `floorcap(1, maturity, 5)` example in that there isn't any noise from the static class or namespace.

Comment: @Ron Warholic, you are correct. Now I wouldn't actually do this in my code unless there were only a few functions in MathLib that I used extensively.

Comment: Hi actually did think of extension methods but they would also feel different than the normal math code.

Comment: In that case I don't believe you have any other options. You have to qualify your functions or declare them locally. See Mr. Disappointment's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to save on typing you can copy and paste method stubs to each of your client classes.

```
private static double floorcap(double floor, double value, double cap) {
    return MathLib.floorcap(floor, value, cap);
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to say. Probably should make it private though.

Comment: This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - You have to admit it does answer their question.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Yes, but it's still calling the method in a qualified manner internally.  The point is you aren't calling MathLib.floorcap with no qualifier, you are calling a new method unqualified which calls the qualified method.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Through gritted teeth, indeed; though, superficially.

Comment: @James: I doubt that the OP has a particular problem with calling a qualified method. Based on his comments about F#, it seems like he just doesn't like typing the class name every time. To be honest, I'd say the best solution is just to get over it and do it the normal way.

Comment: Hi thanks, indeed this would help, although it's not the 'clean cut' I was looking for. Didn't think it was possible..

Answer (score 0):

The only way that might give you something like what you'd want would be to use extension methods to extend the arithmetic types you want to use:

```
public static class MathLibExt {
  public static double FloorCap(this double value, double floor, double cap) {
    return Math.Min(Math.Max(floor, value), cap);
  }
}

// call like
var value = 25.0;
var capped = value.FloorCap(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this, such as defining a `private static` method in every class that calls your library; however, I would argue that the best solution is just to get over it and type the class name each time.